# woocommerce_form_field radio checked определенный элемент

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Вывожу 2 кнопки. Принципиально нужно, чтобы был чекнутый первый элемент. С таким кодом чекнутый последний, это логично, т.к. для каждого элемента срабатывает checked и остаётся у последнего. Как сделать так, чтобы первый был активен?

```
woocommerce_form_field('custom-region', array(
    'type' => 'radio',
    'options'=> array('one' => 'Раз', 'two' => 'Два'),
    'custom_attributes' => array('checked' => true)
), '');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо `custom_attributes` передайте `default` в массив, последним параметром передается значение по умолчанию, при первом заказе оно будет равно null и будет использовано значение из default. Можете не передавать последний аргумент, тогда всегда по дефолту будет выбрана первая кнопка.

```
woocommerce_form_field('custom-region', array(
        'type' => 'radio',
        'options'=> array('one' => 'Раз', 'two' => 'Два'),
        'default' => 'one',
    ), $checkout->get_value('custom-region'));
```